# Combinatorics journals processing time

Tags: co.combinatorics, journals, soft-question, reference-request

This is a spin-off question from [How to select a journal?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7284/how-to-select-a-journal).  Is there is any data available regarding processing time (acceptance time, time from submission to publication, or similar) specifically for combinatorics journals?  Ideally, this data would be up-to-date.

Comment: Warning: data about processing time typically means averages, not standard deviations.  In my experience, the latter can be so large as to severely limit the usefulness of the former.  In my opinion it is a better bet to find an editor whom you know personally and/or trust to rapidly send the paper to a competent referee.  The practices of the editor count more than those of the journal itself, at least if you're counting time to acceptance (which is what most people care about the most, I think.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is the "backlog" published annually in the AMS Notices.  The latest version is [here (as PDF)](http://www.ams.org/notices/200910/rtx091001316p.pdf).

Comment: I think for more practical purposes, the times from submission to rejection and acceptance are more useful!  I'm not sure the backlog matters at all anymore (at least, not if you post your papers to the arxiv).  In particular, there are some journals with notoriously large backlogs for which the time it takes to reach a decision is, in my limited experience, quite short.

Comment: Though it looks like it's possible to obtain that info from the link you posted.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the "backlog" is more than just the backlog.  It contains a fair bit of information on times.  However, it does not contain the "time to rejection" that you mention which I think would be extremely useful (especially for non-tenured mathematicians) - but that's another debate!

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is about as good an answer as I can expect to get.  (: