# Fast turn-around times 

Tags: journals

This is a very soft question, but it is somewhat relevant to some other questions, like [Which are the best mathematics journals, and what are the differences between them?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42/which-are-the-best-mathematics-journals-and-what-are-the-differences-between-the).

I've read that Notices AMS provides annual (at least) stats on backlogs, turn-around times and so on (when is this, by the way - is it the same month each year? And where is it? The faultless google has let me down ;_;) But what are some of the quickest journals? That being said, one has to balance speed with length of allowed papers (having a page limit of 15 sure would help speed up refereeing times, or am I optimistic?), general reputation and level of specialisation.

What is the quickest journal you are aware of for 'general' papers? For papers in your special field?

Alternatively, what about (unreasonably?) slow turnaround? I'm not asking for anecdotes, but documented evidence (**Edit:** perhaps documented evidence is too strong. I just don't want 'My paper took 3 years because it sat in someone's spam filter and then got lost and then the referee forgot about it'. If you have anecdotal evidence, then it should be either 'common knowledge' or at least corroborated by people you know). If this slow journal is because it accepts top-level research papers that are over 100 pages in length, then please say so.

Comment: I am a bit short on the evidence that you're after, but thought I'd remark that some of the quickest response times I've had has been followed by what, to me at least, seemed quite shoddy post-acceptance-processing. This is to do with the publisher's apparent workflow rather than the journal, of course.

Comment: Where did you read that this is information is published in the Notices of the AMS?  I don't remember every hearing about anything like that.

Comment: @Ben - In the book 'A primer of mathematical writing' (page 82/83 on google books). See the link in the answer by Jason Rute below.

Comment: I am a little worried that the journals which appear as answers to this question would become slower...

Comment: That is a good point. But I would hope that careful consideration of the appropriateness of the journal, its editors and target audience would outweigh the rush by people to see their articles appear quicker. There are constraints at least for Australian mathematicians as to the rankings of journals as seen by our main funding agency which are a huge factor in deciding where to publish. 

Comment: The AMS used to publish this information, but as far as I know they had to stop, because some countries (in Europe, I think) considered this to be advertising (because AMS journals had good turnaround times) and comparisons like this were not permitted in advertising (in those countries).

Answer (score 15):

International Math Research Notices is a journal that accepts `general' papers and has a reputation for turning papers around quickly.  It is in fact part of their mission statement to do so.

Comment: When IMRN first started, they were breathtakingly fast. I published an article in one of the first issues, and I think it took like two weeks from start to end. This was before the internet, so I remember getting proofs by Fedex from Hong Kong.

Comment: Wow! Really before the internet? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet#History. (tongue removed from cheek)

Was it the paper "Existence and regularity of energy-minimizing Riemannian metrics", Int Math Res Notices (1991) Vol. 1991 7-13?

Comment: OK. Maybe I exaggerated. We old guys often do.

Comment: To Deane Yang, IMRN has probably lost the reputation of swiftness for a while, at least for acceptance. Rejection may still be very fast.

Answer (score 12):

I Googled "AMS journal backlog" and found this.

http://www.ams.org/notices/201010/rtx101001331p.pdf

I'm not sure about the other questions.

*EDIT (DR):* [2015 AMS backlog numbers](http://www.ams.org/notices/201510/rnoti-p1266.pdf)

Comment: Ah, there it is.

Comment: 2021: https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/202210/rnoti-p1810.pdf

Answer (score 10):

[Mathematical Research Letters](http://math.ucsd.edu/~mrl/) generally asks referee reports to be returned within a month I think.  It is also ``dedicated to rapid publication of short complete papers of original research in all areas of mathematics.''  It does ask that papers be less than 20 pages though...

However, based on the data in Jason Rute's answer, they don't seem to be super fast...

Answer (score 0):

See this [Elsevier link](https://www.elsevier.com/physical-sciences/fast-publication-in-mathematics-and-statistics) and  [that](https://scirev.org/reviews). People share their experience on the latter.

Comment: That's moderately useful, but since decisions are bimodal, the mean is not a great statistic. Including rejections that happen within a week brings this down a lot, and artificially in my view. The AMS data, providing times to acceptance is much more useful.

Comment: ah, but the AMS data is only time to _acceptance_: it says nothing about fast or slow rejections, which can also both happen.

Comment: For that second link, see more specifically https://scirev.org/discipline/BG01/mathematics/ (and one can change subfield to things like 'Analysis' or 'Geometry and Topology' etc)